ASP.NET Core MVC - generated attributes on header, main, etc
In a web application generated in Visual Studio using the ASP.NET Core MVC template, there are generated attributes on some of the tags in the _Layout.cshtml when the app is run. For example: b-ywrky5rk6w in
<header b-ywrky5rk6w="">
    <nav b-ywrky5rk6w="" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div b-ywrky5rk6w="" class="container-fluid">

Where is that generated from or controlled? I see that a stylesheet in obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle exists. But I don't see how to take advantage of it.

This is part of CSS isolation (sometimes called "CSS scoping" or "scoped styling").  The purpose is to keep the CSS for any given view applicable to only that view.

Thank you for the description and that link.  I see now how it's used and why.

b-ywrky5rk6w are related to scoped CSS in ASP.NET Core.it helps you enables styling specific components without affecting others, this will helps you with the large scale application or reusable components.

Where is that generated from or controlled?

These attributes (b-ywrky5rk6w) are unique identifiers that the ASP.NET Core framework uses to apply scoped CSS rules to specific elements. When you define styles in a scoped CSS file, the framework transforms the CSS selectors to ensure they only apply to the intended elements, adding these attributes to both the HTML elements and the corresponding CSS rules.
In ASP.NET Core, if you create a CSS file with the .cshtml.css extension and place it alongside a Razor view file (.cshtml file), the styles defined in this CSS file are scoped to that view.
For example, if you have _Layout.cshtml, you can create a _Layout.cshtml.css file with the styles you want to be scoped to the _Layout view.
When you build your project, the ASP.NET Core build process generates the unique attribute selectors (like b-ywrky5rk6w) and updates your HTML and CSS to include these attributes. This process is handled during the build and is why you see the generated attributes.

But I don't see how to take advantage of it

To make it work with your application you could follow below steps:
1)Create a CSS file with the .cshtml.css extension next to your Razor view file.
e.g. _Layout.cshtml, create _Layout.cshtml.css.
2)Add your CSS rules in this file. The styles will automatically be scoped to the elements in your view.
3)When you build and run your application, ASP.NET Core will automatically handle the scoping, adding unique attributes to the relevant elements and ensuring your styles are applied only to those elements.

This is a nice description of what I learned from the link that @David pointed me to in his initial comment.
